# Composite primary key in dimension table

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I have a dimension table with composite primary key ex :

**Operateur**:

```
centre
registreDuCommerce
libelleCentre
LibelleRegistreduCommerce
```

The primary key is: `centre, registreDuCommerce`

And the fact table is

**MyFactTable**:

```
col1
col2
col3
centre 
registreDuCommerce
```

> centre and registreDuCommerce ?? centre : Is the code of the city
>   where company is installed registreDuCommerce : idenfiant of the
>   company

And those keys help to identify a company, because we can fine the same `registreDuCommerce` but with different ce.

There is any why to resolve this problem, because I found it's impossible to have composite primary key in dimension table.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not only is it uncommon to have a composite primary key like this, it's uncommon to have a non-synthetic primary key (except for date, perhaps). An integer would be a much more conventional primary key -- you can still place a not null and unique key on these columns.

So you fact table should be made up of integer foreign keys to the dimension tables, along with the metrics.

```
create table dim_customer (
  id         integer primary key,
  first_name character,
  ...

create table dim_item (
  id           integer primary key,
  product_code character unique,
  ...


create table fct_sales (
  item_id     references dim_item(id),
  customer_id references dim_customer(id),
  ...
  sale_amount number
```

When raw data arrives with a product code, you insert into the dim_item table a unique list of all the product codes that do not already exist in it.

When you then load the fact table, you lookup the relevant id for the item from the dim_item table and that value is inserted into the fct_sales table.

When you query the warehouse you join from the fact table to the dimension tables to get the meaningful values (customer name, item code, etc).

Comment: but in datawarhouse modelization, we should have a primary key as one column not a composite primary key

Comment: Yes. "An integer would be a much more conventional primary key".

Comment: can we make something like id_CERC as a primary key to represente the composite primary key? but how can we reference that in the fact table ?

Comment: When you load a (centre and registreDuCommerce) you see if it's already in the dimension table. If it is then you read the unique id number for it and use that in the fact table. If it is not, you insert them, read the newly generated unique id, and use that in the fact table. The foreign key columns in the fact table should all be integers that identify a row in the relevant dimension table.

Comment: because in fact table i will need this  (centre and registreDuCommerce)  to identify the company, for the dimension is OK now, i will add id_dim (surrogate key to present my natural key), but when i want to load data into fact table i will need this id_dim of Operateur table, what should i do to get this id_dim ???

Comment: You load the dimension table with new values first, then read the required ID's by joining your raw data to the dimension tables. If this sounds tricky, you must realise that fact tables are generally trivially simple, but dimension tables can be very difficult. Have a look at the resources here: http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/books/

Comment: first : load dimension table, second load fact table based on natural or surrogate key ??

Comment: surrogate. no natural keys in the fact table

Comment: yes, but i'm talking about generating the foreign key in the fact table, i should make a join operation with a natural key in the dimesnion table

Comment: The dimension table should include the composite key (AKA business key / natural key) as well as the surrogate. Populate the surrogate keys and foreign keys in a staging area *before* you insert them to the dims and facts - much simpler and more efficient that way and it reduces the workload that operates on the Warehouse and Marts.

Comment: dim identifier will be generated automaticaly (auto-increment), i really dot see what you mean with " staging area" is it a temp table in the data warehouse ??

Comment: Look, you really need to go and learn some basics about data warehousing here. There are many great articles by Kimball -- unfortunately you're lacking the understanding of basic concepts and vocabulary at this point.

Comment: because i'm new in data warhousing , and how to design a data warehouse, i'm reading many articles